# Android Camera Error: aec_calculate_sensitivity binning is less than 1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, binning, aec

I am developing an Android app on Unity that uses the Camera (front and back) and once the app starts this error spams about 20 times a second in logcat. It stops when I close my app again. I have tried to find any information about `aec_calculate_sensitivity`, but sadly with no results. It is nothing I define myself. The error also seems to not appear on other applications that use the camera. Does anyone know where to start looking for a cause of this?

I use the Unity and the [CameraCaptureKit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673) of TastyBits

Error log:

> E/mm-camera-CORE(353): aec_calculate_sensitivity binning is less than
>   1

Does anybody have an idea what might cause this?

Comment: consider just using https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52154 - save months of trouble.  or, email those guys with your question - they are the best

Comment: Ok thanks, ill try